# Ancient greek philosophy - looking for a quotation of the kind: "I am scared for the future, I don't trust the youth of today"

Tags: phrase-requests, quotes, philology

I am looking for a famous quotation that was written by an ancient greek philosopher and that basically convey the following idea:

> I am scared for the future, I don't trust the youth of today

Do you know it?

If not, do you know any other famous quotation that convey a similar idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one (*mis*)quote that comes to mind is attributed to [Socrates](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/63219-our-youth-now-love-luxury-they-have-bad-manners-contempt):

> “Our youth now love luxury. They have bad manners, contempt for authority; they show disrespect for their elders and love chatter in place of exercise; they no longer rise when elders enter the room; they contradict their parents, chatter before company; gobble up their food and tyrannize their teachers.”

I doubt he was really scared of the future because of that, though. After all, he was condemned to die for his bad influence on that youth...

Comment: That was the first thing I thought too. However, this is actually a [well-known misquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Socrates#Misattributed). We actually have no direct quotes (or writings) from Socrates, only memories from his students. As near as anyone can tell, this is a paraphrase of [this passage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0241:card%3D961) from a play by Aristophanes. I'm not overly familiar with it, but Socrates was a character in the play. However, it was a comedy, so it was making fun of the guy.

Comment: Thanks for the addition :) I know there are no direct quotes from him - but Plato et al did a good job :P But indeed, it would make sense that he would say this as a comedy character :)